# define double variable in a correct way

Tags: java, variables, double

What is the correct way to define double variable and why?

```
public static final double SCORE = 1;
```

OR

```
public static final double SCORE = 1.0;
```

Thanks

Comment: makes no difference either way

Comment: There's no correct way, both are fine and have the same behaviour.

Comment: Did you try to compile either one?  What would be easier -- trying it yourself, or asking this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no better approach given the two examples shown but there's a subtle difference which probably doesn't matter whether one knows or not.

This subtle difference is that the first example is *widened* from integer to double whereas the second there is no *widening*.

as suggested by Andreas within the comments it's important to note that this is done at compile-time and not at runtime, and as such has no impact whatsoever on generated code and runtime performance. Therefore you may proceed with whatever approach you want.

Comment: But the widening is done by the compiler, not the JVM runtime, so the generated code is *exactly* the same.

Comment: @Andreas completely agree with you, is there any specific part of my answer that is misleading? if so please suggest which part of it. thanks.

Comment: Only that you didn't clarify that it's done at compile-time, not runtime, and as such has no impact whatsoever on generated code and runtime performance. As a "subtle difference", it's only a different to the programmer, not to the JVM.

Comment: Thank you both. I guess it is more clearer to use 1.0.